# run custom django manage.py command with shell script while passing in settings

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, shell

Using django 1.5

I want to use a shell script to run a custom django manage.py command while I'm passing in the settings (i.e. not using the settings from the same directory).

**As an example of passing in my settings, if I run my django development server I'd do so like this:**

`python manage.py runserver ip:port --settings=my.namespace.settings`

In the same directory as my manage.py file, I have my shell script: `myscript`

**Current contents of myscript:**

```
#!/bin/bash
./manage.py shell --settings=my.namespace.settings
```

From the directory of `myscript`, running `./myscript` does indeed give me the django shell with the context of the correct app settings (I've verified that by putting a custom variable, `TEST_VAR`, in my app settings and it outputs correctly in the django shell via `from django.conf import settings` > `settings.TEST_VAR`).

**Now I change `myscript` to run my custom command:**

```
#!/bin/bash
./manage.py custom_command --settings=my.namespace.settings
PROMPT: Unknown command: 'custom_command'
```

I've [followed these instructions](https://django-doc-test1.readthedocs.io/en/stable-1.5.x/howto/custom-management-commands.html) to create my custom django command.

**My directory structure looks as such:**

```
my.namespace
    __init__.py          // & other django app files/dirs
    management           // directory
        __init__.py
        commands         // directory
            __init__.py
            custom_command.py
```

**custom_command.py:**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = 'test'
    help = 'test help'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'test'
```

Again, running `myscript` gives me `unknown command`. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you indent ``handle()`` into the class? Also have you tried running the command "by hand" first?

Comment: @Vedran I've tried both ways. What do you mean run the command 'by hand'? Running the python file gives me errors about not having django environment variables.

Comment: Could you please provide the actual directory structure (with the real namespace and command names) rather than this example?

Comment: ``gives me errors about not having django environment variables`` usually when I get errors like those it's because I'm not sourced into my virtual environment. Are you using virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with you `INSTALLED_APPS` list.  Check your `settings.py` file to confirm that `my.namespace` is included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.